# Web.py Templator Dictionaries

Tags: python, web.py

I'm having problems getting data from a dictionary that I pass to the templator in web.py.

For example, when I render with

```
return render.resp({'foo':'bar'})
```

Then in my template try

```
$def with (test)
$test.foo
```

I get the error "'dict' object has no attribute 'foo'"

Answer (score 2):

That's not the right syntax for accessing a dictionary. Try this:

```
$test['foo']
```

Alternatively, pass in a `web.storage`:

```
return render.resp(web.storage({'foo': 'bar'}))
```